# How can i fill a value from one my domain model to my edit model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

In my project i have : `countries` and `CountryEditModel`.

```
public class countries
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string Code { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CountryEditModel
{
     public int id { get; set; }
     public string Code { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool isvalid{ get;set; }
}
```

`countries` is my domain model which is binded with entity framework and `countryEditModel` is the model which i use in my views.

How can i fill values from `countries` to `countryEditModel`. I actually want to bind list of all countries to dropdownlist in my view and I don't want to use my `countries` domain model directly in my view.

To solve i have done this

```
var countryDomain = context.Country.Select(c => c).ToList();
var countrylist = new List<CountryEditModel>();
var countrymodel = new CountryEditModel();
foreach (var country in countryDomain)
countrymodel = new CountryEditModel()
 {
   Code = country.Code,
   Name = country.Name,
   id = country.id
 };
```

countrylist.Add(countrymodel);

Is there any better way?

Answer:
Actually this is what i exactly wanted to do

```
 var countryViewModel = context.Country.Select(c => new CountryEditModel
                {
                    Code = c.Code,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    id = c.id
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you mean as "bind to dropdownlist"? Do you want to display all countries in drop down list and fill `CountryEditModel` with selected country data?

Comment: I want to list all countries in drop down list but using CountryEditModel

Comment: Please add your own answer as an answer and mark it as such. That closes this question and removes it from the list of questions still seeking an answer.

Comment: I suspect that is not really what you want if you want to display a list of countries in a dropdownlist. For that you need `new SelectList(context.Country. "id ", "Name")` assuming you want to bind a property to the country ID and display the country Name for use in `@Html.DropDownListFor()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the @rohitsingh this is what he exactly wanted to do

```
var countryViewModel = context.Country.Select(c => new CountryEditModel
    {
        Code = c.Code,
        Name = c.Name,
        id = c.id
    }).ToList();
```